# I have worked at Google (before) - does omitting "before" change the meaning?

Tags: meaning, present-perfect

When talking about a person's background, are the "before" necessary? If I don't add it, does that mean that I am still doing that?

Is my understanding below correct?

**Example 1**

> I have worked at Google.

Whether I am still working at Google is unclear.

> I have worked at Google before.

Something in the past.

**Example 2**

> I have been a programmer.

Whether I am still programmer is unclear.

> I have been a programmer before.

Something in the past.

**Example 3**

> I have lived in Sydney.

Whether I still live in Sydney is unclear.

> I have lived in Sydney before.

Something in the past.

Comment: Including "before" is unnecessary - we'd only do it for emphasis in certain contexts. ***I have done X*** almost always implies ***I'm no longer doing X*** (except in contexts like ***I have been jogging every morning lately***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers so the "before" in all of the examples are optional. Without it, they convey the same meaning, is that right?

Comment: That's what I said, yes.

Comment: Don't use **before** unless something in the present context implies you *are or will be* doing it **again**.  Example:  "I've worked at Google before" strongly implies you had worked there previously, quit, then re-applied or are considering reapplying.

Answer (score 2):

> When talking about a person's background, are the "before" necessary?

No, adding "before" is not necessary. Each of your sentences is correct and natural without it.

> If I don't add it, does that mean that I am still doing that?

No, omitting "before" does not mean that you're still doing the activity. When you omit it, it's unclear whether you're still working at Google, still a programmer, or still living in Sydney.

> Is my understanding below correct?

I think so, although I'm not entirely sure about what your understanding is. Adding "before" in those sentences would normally mean that the action was not currently occurring. Of course, there can be exceptions; without more context, it's impossible to give a definitive answer.